# Push notification not working on production

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When i was using development certificate push notifications were perfectly working. But today when my app goes live i changed ck.pem to distribution. Now I am getting device tokens but not getting push notifications. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use production certificate for push notifications, you need to remove .sandbox in the apns server address and if you install the app by using Xcode, generally by using run option, then the mode will be set to development and the push notifications from production environment won't be received. You need to install the app by generating the .ipa file and install in from iTunes.

Comment: Thank you so much. Removing .sandbox solved my problem.

Comment: Okay. I also got the same issue for my first app. And accept the answer if your problem is solved. Cheers :)